# UICollectionReusableView change header hight with animation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have collectionView with header,
the first size of the header is X and i want to change it to x+50 but with animation.
but when i change the header frame its just go over the viewcells.

```
    HeaderCollectionView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:KCollectionHeaderIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    headerView.frame = CGRectMake(headerView.frame.origin.x, headerView.frame.origin.y, headerView.frame.size.width, self.h);
```

sometimes  self.h get different sizes;

thanks.

Comment: Did you found solution? ..as I'm trying to do exactly the same

Answer (score 4):

Change the header size in

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

When you want to change the header size call reloadData delegate method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This method is defined in UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.